# MySQL - How do find a date using a specific minimum time interval over the entire history of the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that tracks shares sold by executives at publicly-traded companies. I am trying to create a query where I can identify any executive who sold shares for the first time in 10 or more years (and identify the date they sold on). The database goes back well over 20 years.

The table called "fact_insider_sales" has several columns of data. Here is a partial list of the relevant columns:

id

ticker_id (stock ticker)

stock_id (stock name)

filer_id (executive's name)

relationship_id (executive's title)

transaction_date (date of sale)

shares (how many shares were sold on that date)

Sometimes, an executive sells often and sometimes they sell infrequently. The table only captures data when the executive sells any amount of shares and captures the date that he/she sold the shares. The relevant column that I'm trying to work with to make this query is the "transaction_date" and the "transaction_date" data is in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

In essence, I'm trying to identify any transaction date over the entire history of the database where that executive sold for the first time in 10 or more years.

I've thought about using the max() and min() functions as well as datesub() but I can't seem to come up with the correct logic to find where the data meets this discrete time interval within the broader database. All of my other queries focus on the most recent sales activity over the near-term, using coding language like this example tracking sales in the last 30 days (which isn't going to work for this purpose):

```
a.transaction_date >= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 Day)
```

Here is what I have so far on the query I can't seem to complete:

```
SELECT 
e.stock_name,     
e.stock_id,
f.ticker_id,
f.ticker_name,
a.transaction_date,
d.filer_name,
b.relationship_name,
b.relationship_id
FROM fact_insider_sales as a 
join dim_relationship as b ON (a.relationship_id = b.relationship_id)
join dim_filer as d on (a.filer_id = d.filer_id)
join dim_stock as e on (a.stock_id = e.stock_id)
join dim_ticker as f ON (a.ticker_id = f.ticker_id)
WHERE a.transaction_date ??????????????????????????????? 
and b.relationship_name IN ('CEO', 'CB')
```

Can anyone provide their expertise to create the right logic and get this transaction date time period correct? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query starting 10 years back from the current date, you could use:

```
WHERE a.transaction_date <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 year)
```

This will give you all the transaction 10 years ago, but still not show you the first time. For this you will need a subquery to find that specific data by executive.

```
SELECT filer_id,min(transaction_date) AS first_time
FROM fact_insider_sales
WHERE transaction_date <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 year)
GROUP BY filer_id
```

Now include this query as table on your original query:

```
SELECT 
e.stock_name,     
e.stock_id,
f.ticker_id,
f.ticker_name,
a.transaction_date,
d.filer_name,
b.relationship_name,
b.relationship_id
FROM fact_insider_sales as a
JOIN (SELECT filer_id,min(transaction_date) AS first_time
    FROM fact_insider_sales
    WHERE transaction_date <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 year)
    GROUP BY filer_id) AS p
  ON a.filer_id=p.filer_id
JOIN dim_relationship as b ON (a.relationship_id = b.relationship_id)
JOIN dim_filer as d on (a.filer_id = d.filer_id)
JOIN dim_stock as e on (a.stock_id = e.stock_id)
JOIN dim_ticker as f ON (a.ticker_id = f.ticker_id)
WHERE a.transaction_date = p.first_time
AND b.relationship_name IN ('CEO', 'CB')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The structure you suggested is excellent and it makes sense to add a subquery. However, I'm getting an error when I run it that says:   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.relationship_id' in 'on clause'. Is it possible we introduced some issues by adding the subquery? There hadn't previously been any problems with the 'a.relationship_id' on clause before. I can usually trouble-shoot minor problems but this has me stumped now.

Comment: @Marisa3300 The subquery added is using traditional join syntax instead of ANSI like the rest of your joins. Join methods can't be mixed and matched... only one can be used. You'll want to change it to `JOIN` ..subquery...`ON a.filer_id=p.filer_id`.

Comment: Thanks @Mallorie for the edit. I wrote this on the fly.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the clarification Mallorie! I really appreciate it!! You guys are amazing and now I have a lot to work with so that I can complete the query. Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With this query, you could either create a view out of it like in my example, or simply join the query in your `FROM` clause:

[Click here for dbfiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4W2NxbAztq7DbLhm9zUqpX/1)

Create view that lists each `filer_id` sale, and the difference in years from the next oldest `transaction_date` for that `filer_id`:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_date_diff AS
SELECT  f1.id, 
        f1.filer_id, 
        f1.transaction_date AS transaction_date1, 
        MAX(f2.transaction_date) AS transaction_date2, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, MAX(f2.transaction_date), f1.transaction_date) AS year_diff
FROM    fact_insider_sales f1
        LEFT JOIN fact_insider_sales f2
            ON f1.filer_id = f2.filer_id
            AND f2.transaction_date < f1.transaction_date
GROUP BY f1.id, f1.filer_id, f1.transaction_date;
```

And then join the view in your query, only selecting `id`s where the `year_diff` is >= 10 years:

```
SELECT 
e.stock_name,     
e.stock_id,
f.ticker_id,
f.ticker_name,
a.transaction_date,
d.filer_name,
b.relationship_name,
b.relationship_id
FROM fact_insider_sales as a 
join dim_relationship as b ON (a.relationship_id = b.relationship_id)
join dim_filer as d on (a.filer_id = d.filer_id)
join dim_stock as e on (a.stock_id = e.stock_id)
join dim_ticker as f ON (a.ticker_id = f.ticker_id)
JOIN sales_date_diff s ON a.id = s.id
WHERE s.year_diff >= 10
and b.relationship_name IN ('CEO', 'CB')
```